# Can UITableView's scroll 'smoothly' when using various height Self Sizing Cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView with Custom UITableViewCell's. The Cell's can vary between 200.0 and 300.0 and height.

Now if you open Facebook, you'll notice the scrolling in the News Feed is awfully choppy. However, this is likely due to that various videos that are loaded on every cell, and that the time taken in cellForRowAtIndexPath is greater than 13.67ms (1s/60frames). Hence the choppy 'flicker'.

Quora on the other hand has cells that are varying heights, between probably 150.0 and 400.0+. It scrolls pretty smoothly however.

Now, when I scroll my tableView it's as though my screen is 'jumping'. I will scroll down, and every now and then (may every new cell dequeue but not quite), it's as if something higher up in the tableview got a few pixels shorter in height, and therefore the screen i'm currently viewing jumped up a few pixels. (This is not what's happening, I'm just trying to paint a picture of what it looks like).

Now I know it's not a time related issue. My cellForRowAtIndexMethod is nowhere near 13.67ms. It's always around 3ms, so that's not the issue.

2 questions...

1) Is this typically indicative of an auto layout issue?

2) Is there an accurate/semi-accurate way to calculate estiamtedRowHeight when you have such varied cell heights, or would having an accurate number here not fix this issue anyway? Just an idea.

Comment: Did you apply transformation to yours subview layers (I mean rounded corners, shadows effects etc...)?

Comment: @MacKentoch No, I have none of that stuff. Very simple couple of views and labels. A handful of self sizing labels though.

Comment: I just know that transformations to layer cost too much and make scrolling not smooth. But right now I don't see... Maybe you add images? It is strange...